# Extracting data from multiple NetCDF files from multiple locations at specific date

Tags: python, netcdf, temporal

I am trying to extract from multi-temporal files (netCDF) the value of the pixel at a specific location and time.

Each file is named: `T2011`, `T2012`, and so on until `T2017`.
Each file contains 365 layers, every layer corresponds to one day of a the year and that layer expresses the temperature of that day.

My goal is to extract information according to my input dataset.
I have a csv (`locd.csv`) with my targets and it looks like this:

```
id      lat         lon     DateFin    DateCount
1   46.63174271 7.405986324 02-02-18    43,131
2   46.64972969 7.484352537 25-01-18    43,123
3   47.27028727 7.603811832 20-01-18    43,118
4   46.99994455 7.063905466 05-02-18    43,134
5   47.08125481 7.19501811  20-01-18    43,118
6   47.37833814 7.432005368 11-12-18    43,443
7   47.43230354 7.445253182 30-12-18    43,462
8   46.73777711 6.777871255 09-04-18    43,197
69  47.42285191 7.113934735 09-04-18    43,197
```

The `id` is the location I am interested in, `lat` and `lon`: latitude and longitude),  `DateFin` correspond to the date I am interested to know the temperature at that particular location and `DateCount` corresponds to the number
of days from `01-01-1900` to the date I am interested in (that's how the layers are indexed in the file).

For doing that I have something like this:

```
import glob
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import os 

# Record all the years of the netCDF files into a Python list
all_years = []

for file in glob.glob('*.nc'):
    print(file)
    data = Dataset(file, 'r')
    time = data.variables['time'] # that's how the days are stored
    year = file[0:4]
    all_years.append(year)


# define my input data
cities = pd.read_csv('locd.csv')

# extracting the data 
for index, row in cities.iterrows():
    id_row = row['id'] # id from the database
    location_latitude = row['lat']
    location_longitude = row['lon']
    location_date = row['DateCount'] #number of day counting since 1900-01-01

    # Sorting the all_years python list
    all_years.sort()

    for yr in all_years:
        # Reading-in the data 
        data = Dataset(str(yr)+'.nc', 'r')

        # Storing the lat and lon data of the netCDF file into variables 
        lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
        lon = data.variables['lon'][:]

        # Squared difference between the specified lat,lon and the lat,lon of the netCDF 
        sq_diff_lat = (lat - location_latitude)**2 
        sq_diff_lon = (lon - location_longitude)**2

        # Identify the index of the min value for lat and lon
        min_index_lat = sq_diff_lat.argmin()
        min_index_lon = sq_diff_lon.argmin()

        # Accessing the precipitation data
        prec= data.variables['precipi'] # that's how the variable is called 


        for p_index in np.arange(0, len(location_date)):
            print('Recording the value for '+ id_row+': ' + str(location_date[p_index]))
            df.loc[id_row[location_date]]['Precipitation'] = prec[location_date, min_index_lat, min_index_lon]

    # to record it in a new archive
    df.to_csv('locationNew.csv')
```

**My issues:**

I don't manage to make it work.  Every time there is a new thing coming, now it says that `"id_row" must be a string`.

Does anybody have a hint or experience working with these type of files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete traceback for the error.

Comment: Your current error is coming from the `print`, where you're trying to concatenate `id_row` with a string: `'Recording the value for ' + id_row + ...`. The error indicates `id_row` is *not* a string at that time. I'd try removing that line and see what error you get.

Comment: @Martineau that's all error.  If I removed completed the line:  `print('Recording the value for '+ id_row+': ' + str(location_date[p_index]))` , then error says that in this line `for p_index in np.arange(0, len(location_date)): location_date has no len()`, If i remove `len()` it says `IndexError: index exceeds dimension bounds`